# Join on the same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, self-join

As an example of what I'm looking for, consider the following example Fruits table

```
id  user_id     fruit           type        

1   43      apple           fresh
2   87      watermelon      fresh
3   99      apple           fresh
4   43      pineapple       dried
5   60      pineapple       dried
6   60      lemon           fresh
7   99      kiwi            fresh   
8   43      mango           fresh
```

I want to find all the records for all users that have both "apple" AND "dried" in the same table (not necessarily in the same row at the same time). The same user must have both conditions.

What I'd like returned is:

```
id  user_id     fruit           type        

1   43      apple           fresh
4   43      pineapple       dried
```

I've tried several combinations of self joins:

```
SELECT distinct f1.*, f2.*
FROM orders f1 FULL JOIN orders f2
ON f1.user_id = f2.user_id
WHERE f1.fruit ILIKE 'apple'
AND f2.type ILIKE 'dried'
```

but haven't been able to get it quite right.

This is for a Rails application so I'd love to be able to do this with ActiveRecord but I will be happy with plain SQL, if need be.

Any suggestions for how to do this? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Fruits
WHERE
  (Fruit = 'apple'
OR Type = 'dried')
AND
    EXISTS
    (SELECT
        NULL
    FROM 
        FRUITS F1
        INNER JOIN Fruits F2 ON F1.User_ID = F2.User_ID AND F1.Fruit = 'apple' and F2.Type = 'dried'
    WHERE
        Fruits.user_ID = F1.User_ID)
```

Comment: Hi.  Same as my comment above:  this is giving me all 3 records (1,4,and 8) instead of just 2 records searched (1 and 4)

Comment: @purplerice I've edited to add additional where clauses. You weren't exactly clear when you said you wanted ALL records for ALL users that have both apple and dried in the same table. You didn't mention you only wanted the rows that contain apple or dried - See here for working example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37dcd/6

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Sorry I wasn't more clear - I gave the result I was looking for since it's not always easy to explain.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  orders.*
FROM
  orders
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE fruit = 'apple' GROUP BY user_id) AS apple_buyers
    ON apple_buyers.user_id = orders.user_id
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE type  = 'dried' GROUP BY user_id) AS dried_buyers
    ON dried_buyers.user_id = orders.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but almost.  This is giving me all 3 records for the user_id instead of just the specific 2 (I'm getting back record id #s 1,4 and 8 instead of just #s 1,4.

Comment: @purplerice - Just add `WHERE orders.fruit = 'apple' OR orders.type = 'dried'` to the existing query.  Depending on your indexes *(I recommend [user_id, fruit] **and** [user_id, type] indexes)* and your particular RDBMS, different queries will perform differently.  This may or may not be faster than the correlated sub-query version from Tobsey.  You would need to test on your real environment with data representative of a live environment.

Comment: This also works great.  I chose the correct answer that was given first but I wish I can also accept yours instead of just +1 it.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  TAB1.id,TAB1.user_id,TAB1.fruit,TAB1.types

FROM 
 (select id,user_id,fruit,types
 from IID T1 WHERE  T1.fruit='apple' OR T1.types ='dried')TAB1

  INNER JOIN 

 (select user_id,count(user_id) AS CNT_user_id
  from IID T1 WHERE  T1.fruit='apple' OR T1.types ='dried'
  group by user_id
  having count(user_id) >=2)TAB2

  ON(TAB1.user_id=TAB2.user_id)

 id user_id    fruit        types
 4      43     pineapple    dried
 1      43     apple        fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id , A.user_id,A.fruit,A.types  FROM iid A 
WHERE user_id IN(
    SELECT A.user_id FROM 
    (
        SELECT user_id FROM iid 
        WHERE types='dried'
    )A
 INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT user_id FROM iid WHERE fruit = 'apple'
    )B
ON A.user_id=b.user_id)
AND ( fruit='apple' OR types='dried')
```